# Communication between Zend modules

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to communicate between Zend Modules as stated below?

I want $sVariable to return "bla". But it gives me

```
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ActionStack Object.
```

In one module call:

```
$sVariable = $this->_helper->actionStack('login', 'index', 'user');
echo $sVariable;
```

And in the other module:

```
class User_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return "bla";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option was using Zend_Regsitry. In loginAction() you can do:

```
Zend_Registry::set('bla', $aUserData['sVariable']);
```

And to get it back you can do.

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
echo ($registry['sVariable']);
```

But it was messy. So i moved what was in my controller action to a helper. That fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not a good practice but if you still want to make it work do echo instead of return

```
class User_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function loginAction(){
        echo "bla";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not best practice to communicate across module controllers. Can this variable / logic be moved into a model? Working with models across modules is made pretty simple by the autoloader.

Comment: If this was supposed to be the answer, it should have been backed up with some code example or link. If this was just a suggestion or comment, you could have used the comment link.

Comment: There is no comment link for me (due to fresh reputation). :-)